# Bingmaps API. PolyLines located in different semispheres

Tags: angular, bing-maps

In my project I use BingMaps for Angular2. There are routes on the map. Every route conists of few polylines.

This specific case is for route that has 2 polylines. One polyline has points with longitudes from 129 to 179.9. Second polyline has points from 180.1 to 230. So, overall there should be polyline from 129 to 230. But its not...see screenhot. The problem is that route is rendered on different sides of the map.

Screenshot: 
https://www.screencast.com/t/Vr0epeo9xi5

Overall, the behavior is really strange. 
Video: 
https://www.screencast.com/t/2dbmYGZP

Has anyone any ideas how to fix it and build polyline that crosses longitude = -180 or 180?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue by upgrading bingmaps to V8.
Now route is ok, however there margins of east/west, but this works for us.

[image]